# Restore site without back up

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

First time posting In a forum so excuse me if I ramble on.
Running sp2010

I run two different app pools on the same SP farm. When I've made changes to one site, I replicate them on the other using powershell commands

`backup_spsite  -identity "mysite1" -path c:\filename`

`Restore-spsite -identity "mysite2" -path c:\filename -dbname "mysite2DB" -FORCE`

Before I did this I normally take a back up of the site that I'm writing over. I forgot this time and I have some users complaining they have lost work (despite being told which site to use)

Is there any way I can recover the site I wrote over?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You already overwrite the site collections, So now only option is if you have Content database's backup where the site collection is hosted.

- You have to restore the backup of database from previous date.
- Restore it in lower / other/ test farm.
- Now, in that farm. you can either move the required stuff manually or take the backup of site collection and overwrite it back to main farm.